# Multiple query Records Vbscript

Tags: vbscript, bartender

Pulling multiple records onto one label is not supported in the currently released version of BarTender. So I heard that a VBScript can help me to achieve this. I never touch this before, so sorry for my lack of comprehension

I am trying to create a VBScript that connect to my database and execute the following query :

```
select Quantite, description_device
from utilise, medical_devices
where utilise.id_operation = 25
and utilise.id_dispositif = medical_devices.id_device
```

I created this :

```
Dim cn, rs

set cn = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
set rs = CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")
cn.connectionString = "Driver={MySQL ODBC 5.3 Driver};Server=myip;Database=mydb;User=myuser; Password=mypassword;"
cn.open
rs.open "select ...", cn, 3
rs.MoveFirst
while not rs.eof
    wscript.echo rs(0)
    rs.next
wend
cn.close
```

But even the first line fail with this error : `<Line 1: Value = Dim cn, rs: Syntax error>`

How to proceed to get this script running?

Comment: The error message text does not sound like any `cscript` or `wscript` one. Save your code as e.g. `31477705.vbs` and then invoke `cscript 31477705.vbs`  from a command prompt window. Check file type association:  `assoc .vbs` should return `.vbs=VBSFile` and `ftype VBSFile` should return something like `VBSFile="%SystemRoot%\System32\WScript.exe" "%1" %*`

Comment: I think I understand where the mistake comes. I use Bartender, a program that create bar code. But I need to use a vbscript to bypass 
the shortcomings of this software. I will post a topic on the bartender dedicated forum... Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Are you using Bartender Software to create the VBScript?

You have to choose **Multi-Line Script** under **Script Type**

[image]